# Implementing multitenancy in Spring MVC application with a master database?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, multi-tenant

I'm trying to create an application implementing a multitency concept with separate databases, using Spring MVC, Spring security, Hibernate and MySql based on this code source [demo](https://github.com/DhyanandraSingh/appointment-mt).

I need to add a default database to store tenants metadata and relative databases.

Please if you have any further ideas, tutoriels or examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are asking to add tutorials or samples.

Please refer below :

https://dzone.com/articles/multi-tenancy-using-jpa-spring-and-hibernate-part

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but i still need to know how to add a default database to store tenants and their data (Database names, tenants, usernames, passwords, server urls ...)

Answer (score 0):

very detailed explanation and example on how to implement default database for storing your users and other shared information is [here](https://sultanov.dev/blog/schema-based-multi-tenancy-with-spring-data/)

another grate example is [here](https://medium.com/swlh/multi-tenancy-implementation-using-spring-boot-hibernate-6a8e3ecb251a):

I actually build my own solution based on those two articles.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.